# new Date() have different output in app.js and ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
var d = new Date();
res.send(d);
});
```

This give output "2019-03-19T04:50:47.710Z" which is UTC when i visit through mydomain/test

```
app.get("/testejs",function(req,res){
res.render("testejs");});
```

My testejs below-

```
<%= new Date() %>
```

This ejs when visited through mydomain/testejs gives output -

Tue Mar 19 2019 12:55:52 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

How is this possible that new Date() give me two different output from( app.js and testejs.ejs ) but it is executed on same server?

Comment: When I try to organise an event at 9 AM IST , it is saved in UTC as 01:**:** . It should save it as 3:30 UTC as I am organising it from date picker from my browser .

Comment: I tried to change the server time to IST . And when I check the date using terminal it shows me correct time in IST. But in the background it is saving it as Singapore local time.

Comment: Does anyone have any clue why terminal is giving IST and server is saving data in UTC by substracting 8 hrs from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,
Remember that app.js is running on the server side and ejs on the browser, the browser date format is different from the server.

Comment: As per documents says - EJS is a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript. I think it execute the file in server and send a simple HTML to the client. Am I right?

Comment: You are right @VikramRay, just print your d variable passed from the server to client site by <%= d %>  and your format will be consistent.

Comment: Got that . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Date().toLocaleString()
```

[Click here Out put is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiN14.png)

#### OR

```js
new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()
```

#### Sample Out Put nodejs backend and frontend ejs using date function 3/19/2019, 10:58:31 AM

Comment: getFullYear() Get the year as a four digit number (yyyy)
getMonth() Get the month as a number (0-11)
getDate() Get the day as a number (1-31)
getHours() Get the hour (0-23)
getMinutes() Get the minute (0-59)
getSeconds() Get the second (0-59)
getMilliseconds() Get the millisecond (0-999)
getTime() Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
getDay() Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
Date.now() Get the time. ECMAScript 5.

Comment: if you want same date and time show in client side then you can pass data from server side to client side 
step 1: app.js
 res.render('pages/home',{"serverdate":new Date().toLocaleString()});
step 2: ejs file 
<%= serverdate %>

Comment: Will keep that in mind and try to use .tolocalString .

Answer (score 0):

new Date() generates a date value, which is a number of milliseconds since a base time, usually Jan 1, 1970.  The exact value depends on the setting of the clock on the server where the value is generated.

That value can be displayed in various ways.

Depending on the default settings of the client environment,
that my be in UTC, or the local [or some other] time zone,
and in various formats.

Note that 04:50 UTC and 12:55 GMT+0800 are about 5 minutes apart,
but in different time zones.  If this was two tests run 5 minutes
apart, that would explain the difference.

Instead of using the default toString() method to display the times,
use getTime() to see what the raw number is.

Answer (score 0):

They both are not two different dates but the same date in different timezones.

Reason for the different format is how the toString() method is written for the Date object, 
the toString() method is written in a way to return the UTC formatted date so when you send it on the browser it calls the toString for the date as everything will be converted into a string before mounting.

new Date() invokes the constructor and return the date instance which also will have all its methods, however, Date() is a function which returns the stringified date.

See the examples below

```js
date = new Date('Tue Mar 19 2019 12:55:52 GMT+0800')

console.log(date)
console.log('toString-%s',date.toString())
console.log('toString-%s',''+date)
console.log('Tue Mar 19 2019 12:55:52 GMT+0800')
//Managing offsets
console.log(Date('Tue Mar 19 2019 12:55:52 GMT+0800'))
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (8-5.5)*60*1000 );
console.log(date)
```